# How can combine this two tables and create a new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to combine two tables and create a new table

first table :

```
ExitDate      |   fullname     | outputnumber    
------------------------------------------------
2012/01/01         a              10    
2012/01/06         b              2    
2012/01/08         c              3    
2012/01/12         d              4
```

second table

```
inputnumber   |   date
-------------------------------
  100              2012/01/05
  150              2012/01/07
  200              2012/01/10
```

the answer table

```
ExitDate      |   fullname     | outputnumber    |   inputnumber   |   date

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2012/01/01         a              10                      -             -
     -             -              -                       100          2012/01/05
2012/01/06         b              2                       -               -
      -            -              -                       150          2012/01/07
2012/01/08         c              3                       -             -
    -              -              -                       200         2012/01/10
2012/01/12         d              4                       -             -
```

note : the date and location is important  and i using sql server

Comment: It seems you need `union all`

Comment: @Oto Shavadze : can you tel me  a query please

Comment: What you mean when you say `location`? order of combined rows

Comment: its mean that  the date field in second table is between exitdate in first table

Comment: What about having one date field and number field instead of two? ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can have a better table like this:

```
select *
from (
    select fullname, 0 as io, outputnumber as number, ExitDate as date
    from table1
    union all
    select '-', 1, inputnumber, date) t
order by date, io;
```

```
fullname | io | number | date
---------+----+--------+-------------
a        | 0  | 10     | 2012/01/01
-        | 1  | 100    | 2012/01/05
b        | 0  | 2      | 2012/01/06
-        | 1  | 150    | 2012/01/07
c        | 0  | 3      | 2012/01/08
-        | 1  | 200    | 2012/01/10
d        | 0  | 4      | 2012/01/12
```

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand, you need `union all`. Something like this  :

```
select * from (
    select ExitDate, fullname, outputnumber, NUll as inputnumber, NUll as [date] from first_table
    union all
    select NUll as ExitDate, NUll as fullname, NUll as outputnumber, inputnumber, [date] from second_table
) t
order by coalesce(ExitDate, [date])
```

Then entire result is sorted by combined dates from `ExitDate` and  `date` columns

[rextester demo](http://rextester.com/NTAUA53050)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the exact output you want using `full outer join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1 full outer join
     t2
     on 1 = 0
order by coalesce(t1.exitdate, t2.date);
```